# SSRS SubReport Display across multiple columns in parent

Tags: reporting-services, subreport

In SSRS I have created two tables, a parent and a subreport. Both reports retrieve the information correctly, however, I was hoping to find out if there was a way to format the report so as to not waste space.

My question is really this. The main report has 10 columns of returned information. The subreport has 4 columns. I would like the subreport to appear below the main reports row of data in the second column. Is there anyway to tell the report to expand the subreport without widening the column where it is placed.

Here is what I have in design(Example not the full structure)

```xml
<MainHeader1><MainHeader2><MainHeader3><MainHeader4><MainHeader5>
<MainData1  ><MainData2  ><MainData3  ><MainData4  ><MainData5  >
<Blank      ><Subreport  ><Blank      ><Blank      ><Blank      >
```

When I preview the report this is what I see

```xml
<MainHeader1><MainHeader2                   ><MainHeader3><MainHeader4><MainHeader5>
<MainData1  ><MainData2                     ><MainData3  ><MainData4  ><MainData5  >
<Blank      ><Subreport                     ><Blank      ><Blank      ><Blank      >
```

What I would like to see is this

```xml
<MainHeader1><MainHeader2><MainHeader3><MainHeader4><MainHeader5>
<MainData1  ><MainData2  ><MainData3  ><MainData4  ><MainData5  >
<Blank      ><Subreport                            ><Blank      >
```

I am not sure if that makes sense but any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can merge cells horizontally in SSRS.

Simply select the three cells that you would like the subreport to span, right click and select Merge Cells.

Comment: Wow that was way easier than I made it out to be. Thanks so much!